# Create 1 xpath with multiple css classes

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to create a xpath where i can check the data from multiple classes

I like to check that when i have Test Message , CheckMessage and Administrator my xpath is correct:

[image]

Comment: Please share the HTML in the form of text, not image.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your exact query. Refer the below XPath expressions, hope they help.

- This should list out all the `<span>` elements within the table `<tbody>` which has attribute `role=rowgroup`

```
//tbody[@role='rowgroup']//span
```

- This should list out all the `<span>` with attribute `class=ng-binding` elements within the table `<tbody>` which has attribute `role=rowgroup`

```
//tbody[@role='rowgroup']//span[@class='ng-binding']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying What i am searching for it more like (draft):

//span[@class='ng-binding, (contains(text(),'Test Message' and (contains(text(),'CheckMessage' and (contains(text(),'Administrator')]